# Formalize a phrase

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was asked to write a formal phrase of the type {|}  which does not uses $ \forall$ and $ \exists $

The phrase is: 
"The set of all positive natural numbers which among their prime factors appear 2 and 3 and they have no other prime factors."

We say that $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ and we are asked for only the positive natural numbers.

the only thing I manage to formalize is
$ \forall n \{\ n \in N \space | \space \exists \space k , m \in N. \space n=2^k*3^m  \}$

But it's with the $\exists$ and $\forall$ signs which are not allowed.

Can someone give me a hint?

Many thanks!

Comment: @LordSoth: Ah! It seems that we're using two different definitions of $\mathbb{N}$. I was assuming $\mathbb{N}$ did not include $0$, but it seems more in line with Splash's question to assume $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ (based on the assumption "... set of all *positive* natural numbers ..."). I've removed my uneditable edited comment. What a funny double misunderstanding! `:)`

Comment: You right! I forgot to mention it.
Usually in calculus we say it's without the zero, but here the teacher said we should include it.
Sorry, my fault.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $0 \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$
\{2^{k+1} 3^{m+1} \mid k,m \in \mathbb{N}\}
$$
works. If $0 \not\in \mathbb{N}$, then replace $k+1$ and $m+1$ by $k$ and $m$ (respectively).

Comment: Ok, this should be fine. I guess one source of confusion for me was that the wording of the main question is kind-of weird. We do not include $1$ as $1$ has no prime factors, and we do not include $2$ and $3$ as they only have $2$ or $3$ as prime factors, but not $2$ and $3$ at the same time.

Comment: @LordSoth: Yeah it confused me, too. The description of the set could definitely be phrased in a nicer way.

Comment: Of course this is a differnet kind of construct: $\{\,x\in A\mid \phi(x)\,\}$ is a manifestation of the comprehension axiom scheme, whereas this answer is of the form  $\{\, f(x)\mid x\in A\,\}$ per replacement axiom scheme.

Comment: Which I've always felt is cheating since the quantifiers are "really there", but one does have to admit the typographical characters don't appear on the page! (I mention this to assure the original poster that their intuition that $k,m$ should be quantified is a just intuition, and mathematicians are just frugal with their notation.)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen So do you think a different kind of answer is necessary? (Sorry I am not very familiary with the theory of what you have described).

Answer (score 2):

This one is mean:
$$\left\{n\in\mathbb N\biggm| \frac{6^n}n\in\mathbb N\,\right\}$$
(perhaps setminus $\{1\}$ or $\{1,2,3\}$ or adding the condition $\frac n6\in\mathbb N$, depending on the precise meaning of the problem statement)

Comment: Isn't putting $n|k$ cheating in the form of $\exists m,\, k = nm$?

Comment: @LordSoth considered :)

Comment: Lol, nice! I guess another issue is that $8$ is a member of your set, but I am not sure if it is the member of the set that the OP is asking (the $2$ or $3$, or the $2$ and $3$ unclarity). Perhaps we should wait for him/her to revise.

Comment: @LordSoth Yeah, if $2$ and $3$ are not only *possible* but *mandatory* factors, the condition $\frac n6\in\mathbb N$ should be added.

Comment: Thanks! 
It works, but how come? Why choose to raise 6 to the power of n? 
I can see that it's clearly a big number comparing to n, but for me it seems random choice.